# How to upgrade to Magento 2.1 RC 1 when Magento 2 is installed via GitHub

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.6, magento-2.1

Ok so I'm running Magento 2.0.6 and I have installed it via the GitHub repo.

So as I cannot use the backend upgrade tool, when I upgrade Magento 2 I'm used to run the following:

```
git pull origin
composer update
```

However, when I run those commands, it doesn't upgrade my install to Magento 2.1 RC 1.

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the newly created tag `2.1.0-rc1`

So to upgrade from 2.0.6 to 2.1.0 RC1 when you installed via the GitHub repo you need to do the following:

```
git checkout 2.1.0-rc1
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Raphael, do you know how to do this via composer? I mean if i need to update version of my magento store and all the vendors I'm getting via cimposer and git contains only my /app/code.

Comment: @white-imp hard to tell without knowing the details of your install, I suggest you ask a new question ;)

Comment: I don't know what details more needed for this, but I posted question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117527/how-to-upgrade-magento-to-2-1-0-rc1-via-composer