# How to upgrade magento to 2.1.0-rc1 via composer?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, magento-2.1

I need to upgrade version of my magento base inside store.
All the vendors I'm getting via composer and git contains only my `/app/code` and `/web/composer.json`.
Current version is 2.0.7 and needed version is 2.1.0-rc1.
What can I change inside `composer.json` to get this version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so here's what I would try:

First disable the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:disable
```

Then run:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0-rc1 --no-update
composer update
```

Upgrade the DB schema:

```
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Re enable the cache:

```
php bin/magento cache:enable
```

You can find more details about the upgrade process in the official documentation here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1_RC1CE.html#binstall-using-composerb

Comment: Thanx, very helpful! Don't know why, but  executing "composer require" wasn't work. Looks like it was sleeping. So changing version inside composer.json and "composer update" instead "require" works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Raphael's answer, I believe the correct composer directive is

`composer require magento/project-community-edition 2.1.0-rc1 --no-update`

Answer (score 0):

Download patch ( please view official magento page for details where to download ),

Apply patch

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.0 --no-update
composer update

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Enjoy coding!